# Android how to display arraylist index numbers in my dynamic listview

Tags: android, listview

Sorry for my English,How i can show arraylist index numbers in my dynamic listview?
for example in my app when listview display,in a listview every cell have a index number display like first cell 1,second cell 2,third cell 3 and so on..how i can implement this?Thanks in advance.

This is the screen shot:
in my screen shot see the left int number 1.and now want to in 2nd cell display 2 and so on..

[image]

This is my activity:

```
    public class Artists extends Activity {

   // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // This is not using now if you want you can remove its all references :)
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    ArrayList<AdapterDTOArtist> mAdapterDTOs = null;
    private LazyAdapterArtist mLazyAdatper = null;

    private ArrayList<String> array_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength = 0;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray albums = null;

  LinearLayout ll_artists_chart;
  LinearLayout ll_artists_newrelease;
 private EditText etSearch;

 private static String URL_ALBUMS = "My URL";

  // JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "data";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

private ListView lv = null;
EditText et_artists_searchWord;
// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.artists);

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.artist_main_list_id);

cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

// Check for internet connection
if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
    // Internet Connection is not present
    alert.showAlertDialog(Artists.this,
            "Internet Connection Error",
            "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
    // stop executing code by return
    return;
}

// Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        mAdapterDTOs = new ArrayList<AdapterDTOArtist>();

        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview

        /**
         * Listview item click listener TrackListActivity will be lauched by
         * passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album

            }
        });


ll_artists_chart = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_artists_chart);
ll_artists_newrelease = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_artists_newrelease);
et_artists_searchWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_artists_searchWord);

et_artists_searchWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  ((Filterable) Artists.this.mAdapterDTOs).getFilter().filter(s);
        List<AdapterDTOArtist> list = filter(s.toString(),mAdapterDTOs, true);
        mAdapterDTOs.addAll(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

ll_artists_chart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    //  finish();
    }
});

ll_artists_newrelease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewReleases.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }
  });



}

  /**
  * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
  * */
  class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  /**
   * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
   * */
   @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Artists.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Listing Artists ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * getting Albums JSON
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_ALBUMS);

    // getting JSON string from URL
    //String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET", params);

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    Log.i("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

    try {
        //albums = new JSONArray(json);
        albums = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        if (albums != null) {
            // looping through All albums
            for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item values in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                /*String EateryThmbnailUrl = c
                        .getString(TAG_THMBNAIL_URL);*/
                // ~\/Uploads\/EateryImages\/\/7\/41283f1f-8e6f-42d4-b3c1-01f990efb428.gif
                /*EateryThmbnailUrl = HOST_URL
                        + EateryThmbnailUrl.replace("~", "");*/

                AdapterDTOArtist adapterDTO = new AdapterDTOArtist();

                adapterDTO.setmTag_Id(id);
                adapterDTO.setmTag_Name(name);


            //  adapterDTO.setmImage_URL(EateryThmbnailUrl);

                mAdapterDTOs.add(adapterDTO);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                albumsList.add(map);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
 }

  /**
  * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
  * **/
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            // updating listview
            mLazyAdatper = new LazyAdapterArtist(Artists.this,
                    mAdapterDTOs);
            lv.setAdapter(mLazyAdatper);

            // mLazyAdatper.setDataSet(mAdapterDTOs);

        }
    });

}

}

public static List<AdapterDTOArtist> filter(String string,
    Iterable<AdapterDTOArtist> iterable, boolean byName) {
if (iterable == null)
    return new LinkedList<AdapterDTOArtist>();
 else {
    List<AdapterDTOArtist> collected = new LinkedList<AdapterDTOArtist>();
    Iterator<AdapterDTOArtist> iterator = iterable.iterator();
    if (iterator == null)
        return collected;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        AdapterDTOArtist item = iterator.next();
        collected.add(item);
    }
    return collected;
}
}

}
```

My AdapterDTOArtist class :

```
 public class AdapterDTOArtist {

private String mTag_Id;
private String mTag_Name;

public String getmTag_Name() {
return mTag_Name;
}

public void setmTag_Name(String mTag_Name) {
 this.mTag_Name = mTag_Name;
}

public String getmTag_Id() {
return mTag_Id;
}

public void setmTag_Id(String mTag_Id) {
this.mTag_Id = mTag_Id;
}

}
```

My LazyAdapterArtist class:

```
 public class LazyAdapterArtist extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext = null;
private ArrayList<AdapterDTOArtist> mAdapterDTOs = null;

public LazyAdapterArtist(Context context,
    ArrayList<AdapterDTOArtist> mAdapterDTOs2) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.mContext = context;
this.mAdapterDTOs = mAdapterDTOs2;
}

public void setDataSet(ArrayList<AdapterDTOArtist> adapterDTOs) {
this.mAdapterDTOs = adapterDTOs;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return mAdapterDTOs.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  View row = convertView;
  ViewHolder mHolder = new ViewHolder();

  if (row == null) {
    // Cell is inflating for first time
    row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(com.whizpool.triplevmusic.R.layout.row_artists,
                    null, false);

    mHolder.mNameTxt = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(com.whizpool.triplevmusic.R.id.tv_row_artists);

    row.setTag(mHolder);

} else {
    // recycling of cells
    mHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
}

mHolder.mNameTxt.setText(mAdapterDTOs.get(position).getmTag_Name());

return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {

TextView mNameTxt = null;

}
}
```

just want to display my arraylist cells serialwise like first cell is 1,2nd cell 2 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your listview adapter, on getView() method, you can use the position for that purpose. If you don't have any textView to show the number, first add it to your listview item, then use it in getView() method

Add a new textview to show your position number;

```
static class ViewHolder {
  TextView mNameTxt = null;
  TextView mSeqNo;  //new
}
```

Then use it in getView() method,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  View row = convertView;
  ViewHolder mHolder = new ViewHolder();

  if (row == null) {

   // rest of your code
   mHolder.mSeqNo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);    

    row.setTag(mHolder);

  } else {
    // recycling of cells
    mHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  //rest of your code

  mHolder.mSeqNo.setText("" + position);

  return row;
}
```

Comment: The part of the code that does what you want is `mHolder.mSeqNo.setText("" + position);` the previous part of the code is to recycle old views, when you delete an item from the `ArrayList` this prevents memory leaks and speeds up the process insignificantly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `position` param in `getView` method is sufficient. It starts from 0 (the first index), then 1, 2,3 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
mHolder.mSeqNo.setText("" + (position+1));
```

This would start the seq numbers from 1, like 1, 2, 3,..... and so on to the end of the list. But giving `mHolder.mSeqNo.setText("" + (position)` starts your number from 0, since list starts with 0 (the first value of index). All the best!